# enq: TX - row lock contention ORA-00060 deadlock in production

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, deadlock

these are two SQL statements from different scripts in production environment. There is often situations like they run at the same time, causing error

> ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource

Actual queries

```
UPDATE ITM.SHEL_CAP
SET ITM.SHEL_CAP.SEC_QTY = itm_rec.qty,
ITM.SHEL_CAP.ITMS_TOT_CNT = prim_shel_qty + itm_rec.qty
WHERE ITM.SHEL_CAP.ITM_ID = itm_rec.itm_id;


UPDATE SHEL_CAP
SET SEC_QTY = f_pres_stock,
ITMS_TOT_CNT = PRIM_QTY +f_pres_stock
WHERE ITEM_ID = f_item_id 
AND PRIM_LC_IND = 'Y'
AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

Deadlock from trace file

```
UPDATE ITM.SHEL_CAP
SET ITM.SHEL_CAP.SEC_QTY = :B2 , 
ITEM.SHEL_CAP.ITMS_TOT_CNT = :B3 + :B2 
WHERE ITM.SHEL_CAP.ITM_ID = :B1 


UPDATE SHEL_CAP
SET SEC_QTY = :B2 ,
ITMS_TOT_CNT = PRIM_QTY + :B2 
WHERE ITM_ID = :B1 
AND PRIM_LC_IND = 'Y' 
AND ROWNUM = 1
```

Came to know that it's `enq: TX - row lock contention` from the trace logs.
i have gone through some research regarding how to avoid deadlock despite of row level locking. gone through previous answers in stack overflow as well, and came to know that this should be given attention to the design level adjustments or check if they are any flaws. I have read about threading, parallel to single threading , `INITRANS` adjustments etc.. I am not able to get the clarity on this.

the below are the indexes for the `SHEL_CAP` table

```
CREATE INDEX "ITEM"."XIF506SHEL_CAP" ON "ITM"."SHEL_CAP" ("ITM_ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 65536 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ITEM_INDX01" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Index XPK_SHEL_CAP
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "ITM"."XPK_SHEL_CAP" ON "ITEM"."SHEL_CAP" ("SHEL_POSTN_NUM", "SHEL_NUM", "SEC_NUM", "AI_NUM", "AI_LOC_CD") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 65536 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ITEM_INDX01" ;
```

can any adjustments be done so to avoid such deadlock situations in production? and please provide some good resources to acquire in depth knowledge regarding this and gain mastery over design level optimization.

Comment: `itm_rec` looks like a record, so I suspect the first update is from a cursor loop that updates one row at a time, which could leave it vulnerable to deadlocking if other processing is simultaneously updating the same rows.

Comment: yes @WilliamRobertson you are right! What kind of preventive actions or design level changes can be included so to avoid the deadlock in future?

Comment: Can the loop be replaced with a single update or merge? Or could you lock all the rows to be updated in one go before starting the loop, so that other sessions had to wait for the whole process to complete? Perhaps you could use dbms_lock to let only one of the processes run at a time. It might be possible to reduce deadlocking by ordering the rows to updated in a consistent way, but that's a bit of a guess.